# If ([] == false) is true, why does ([] || true) result in []?

Tags: javascript, comparison, truthiness

Was just doing some testing and I find this odd:

```
[] == false
```

Gives true, this makes sense because double equal only compares contents and not type and tries to do type-coercion.  But if its comparing contents and returns true, that means [ ] is falsey (if you did `[] == true` you get false too), which means:

```
[] || false
```

Should give false, but it gives [ ], making it truthy?  Why?

Another example:

```
"\n  " == 0
```

Gives true, but `"\n  " || false` gives `"\n  "`?  Is there an explanation for this or its just an oddity.

When I tried this in C, we get:

```
int x = "\n " == 0;
printf("%d\n", x);

int y = "\n " || 0;
printf("%d\n", y);
```

Outputs:

```
0
1
```

This makes sense, but given C's influence on Javascript, the behaviour is different.

Comment: `[]` is a *truthy* expression, but `==` performs *coercions*. The rules are covered in [11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) (searching for ["Equality Comparison Algorithm"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22Equality+Comparison+Algorithm%22) will likely find relevant questions).

Comment: See this WTF JS: [All your commas are belong to Array](http://wtfjs.com/2011/02/11/all-your-commas-are-belong-to-Array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type conversion is not related to falsy and truthy values.

What is truthy and what is falsy is defined by the [`ToBoolean`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2) function defined in the specs and `[]` is indeed truthy.

On the other hand, `[] == false` returns `true` because of the [type conversion](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) that happens during the evaluation of the expression.

The rules of type conversion say that for `x == y`

> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

[`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) results in 0 for false so we're left with the evaluation of `[] == 0`. According to the same rules

> If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number, return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

[`ToPrimitive`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1) results in an empty string. Now we have `"" == 0`. Back to our type conversion rules

> If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number,
>   return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

[`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) results in 0 for `""` so the final evaluation is `0 == 0` and that is `true`!

Comment: there is no ToBoolean() in JS, so type conversions are often converted to boolean if a better match is not found. if it can compare as a string or number, it will prefer that before stooping to true/false.

Comment: @dandavis `ToBoolean` as defined by the spec as I said. It's a function used by the JS interpreter, not a JS function

Comment: ok, you're right, but how does that explain why [] is converted to a string to compare to false?

Comment: @dandavis It's all in the links I gave but I edited a complete explanation in my answer.

Comment: @dandavis Glad you appreciate!

Answer (score 3):

"Is false" (even with coercion) is different from "evaluates as false in boolean context."  `obj == false` asks if the object *is* the boolean value `false`, not whether it would evaluate as such if evaluated in boolean context.

You can evaluate an object in boolean context with `(!!obj)`.

```
[] == false;         // true
(!![]) == false;     // false

"\n  " == false;     // true
(!!"\n  ") == false; // false
```

Comment: Not JavaScript.  Whoops.

Comment: @dandavis Fixed.  Thankfully the basic premise of my answer was still valid, just switched some syntax.

Answer (score 0):

from the [ECMA-262 5.1](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11) (page 83):

> If ToBoolean(lval) is true, return lval

```
[] || false; // []
```